# Is there a good syntax highlighting hint for regular expressions?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Looking at [the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), I see that there is no language code for regular expressions, but I wondered if there was a language tag which would give good highlighting for regex's anyway (perhaps one with first-class support for regular expressions, like Perl). Is there?

Ideally I'd like a regex `.*(capturingGroup)[a-z]{1,10}` to be highlighted something like this:

[image]

Comment: Since most regex questions need a language tag as the implementation varies between languages, the syntax highlighting should be picked up by that language's highlighting.  Is this not sufficient?

Comment: When posting a regex on its own (i.e. not in a code snippet), the language syntax highlighting is useless for every tag I've seen. In Java for example regex's are always in a String, so code highlighting doesn't handle them at all. Ideally capturing groups etc. would be highlighted, like on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=.*%28capturingGroup%29[a-z]{1%2C10}&input=)

Comment: Instead of syntax high-lightening, Why don't we implement a feature similar to JSFiddle.  For example http://www.regexplained.co.uk/ (for javascript)  This would better than highlight right?

Comment: The thing about *"posting a regex on its own"* is that "regex" does not actually specify the language you are using. These things come in umpteen different flavors, and though only a few of those make up the bulk of the actually uses there are still *a few* of them.

Comment: How about writing regular expressions in expanded form if they’re that complicated?

Answer (score 2):

This might not provide syntax highlighting, but it provides a nice visual representation and a nice "embedding" function for Stack Overflow.

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)

It looks like this (this is an example from one of my actual answers) :

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cFu6uLgoLLzU_LFT)

So all you have to do is just put the "non-colored" regex over or under and it gives a pretty good visual representation of that regex.

(In that case it was `^\d+(,\d+)*$`)

*Disclaimer : I'm not part of the debuggex project. I am just a user of it, and since I find it is an awesome tool, I decided to show it here.*

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do without every character of every code snippet being rendered in garish colours, as if we were filling up a Kindergarten display wall.

If you are a regex newbie and need to learn to read the expression, you can go to one of those websites like http://regexpal.com or http://regexplained.co.uk; for the rest of us, plain text is fine, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm just trying to imagine the *regexes* required to properly apply syntax highlighting to regexes...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yo, dawg...